# Solr and web site indexing to create a site search

Tags: search, web, indexing, search-engine, solr

I was trying to build a 'site search' on a simple http site.

I have a site, lets call it www.mycompany.com, that is pure html.

Is there an easy way to use solr to index the entire site to build a full text search using solr as the engine?

I googled for a bit and could not find anything specific of the type: 
Do A
Do B
...
profit!

Let me also know if I am a bit off with what is solr for :P

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solr is only for indexing and searching text, it does not have a crawler since it's out the project's scope.

However take a look at [Nutch](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial), which is a crawler and not too hard to setup initially.

Nutch and Solr [can be integrated](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunningNutchAndSolr) if you need some Solr-specific feature to search the index.

Comment: One thing I didn't get was that they are using google site search for search on the http://nutch.apache.org/ site.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ bin/solr create -c corename
$ bin/post -c corename https://siteurl.com -recursive 2 -delay 1
```

This would do a basic index of the site but it would not be the best. If you want simple then there it is. It can be done.

I think this only works on solr 5+.

Answer (score 1):

Two other options you might want to look at are [Crawl Anywhere](http://www.crawl-anywhere.com/) and [Heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org/)